# Unable to run apache dataframe program error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-internals

I am trying to read a CSV file and convert into a Beam dataframe using apache_beam.dataframe.

I am getting the below error whenever I use the beam dataframe library.

Error: AttributeError: type object 'Series' has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append

```
import csv
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.dataframe import convert
input_csv = 'sample.csv'
with open('{0}'.format(input_csv)) as f:
    events = [ dict(row) for row in CSV.DictReader(f)]
```

print(events)

Please discard the above indentation issue and I did not add Apache beam dataframe CSV.reader logic.Issue is that whenever I import apache beam dataframe module I am getting an error.
Please let me know what I am I missing

I am using Apache beam version 2.50.0 in python

Comment: Hi @Adhish, Have you checked this [Github](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/27410) link ? Is this helpful ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh, Thanks.  While going through the stack trace error, i understand that _append() seems to be removed from Pandas. As a workaround i read a CSV file using Beam core API and converted to Dataframe. It works . Creating dataframe from csv file using read_csv() did not work and throws above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/27410), this error is because the function `Series.append` has been removed in Pandas 2.0.0 (refer to this **[document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html)**). Apache Beam doesn't support `Pandas 2.x` since Pandas 2.x removed `append` from `Series` and `Dataframe`. This issue is being tracked in this **[GitHub link](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/27221)**.

As mentioned by @Adhish, as a workaround, you can read a CSV file using the Beam core API and convert it to Dataframe.